# Dynamically changing Elasticsearch logging appender through API

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

TL;DR

In Elasticsearch, can you change the port and remoteHost of a log4j logging appender through the API?

Long version:

We're currently building an ELK stack for logging (Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana). Elasticsearch sends its logs to Logstash through the Log4J protocol.

We have a cluster of 3 Elasticsearch nodes and 3 Logstash instances. We use [Consul](https://consul.io/) for service discovery with [Consul Template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) to generate the config file and restart Elasticsearch if it changes. Here is my logging.yml:

```
Des.logger.level=DEBUG
es.logger.level: INFO
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, socketappender
logger:
  action: DEBUG
  com.amazonaws: WARN

appender:
  socketappender:
   type: org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
   {{ with service "logstash-9500" }}{{ with index . 0 }}port: {{.Port}}
   remoteHost: {{.Address}}{{end}}{{end}}
   layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```

Now I'm trying to change the remoteHost and port through the API to not have to restart the nodes. The documentation gives an example to change the loglevel:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "logger.discovery" : "DEBUG"
    }
 }
```

but after browsing the doc and the code, I can't find if it's the only thing you can do or if anything can be updated.

If it can, I can't find the right path to make it work.

EDIT: For now, I've changed address and port to localhost:9500 and added Balance as a proxy/load balancer to the different Logstash instances. If one Logstash goes down, Balance failover to the next one transparently for Elasticsearch and Consul restarts Balance with the new list of hosts.

Comment: Did you find the answer by chance?

Comment: I needed something similar but it looks like currently you can only change the log level dynamically. For other  logging related changes I guess ES service restart is required.